# Is there a way for Swagger ApiImplicitParam to define separate names for parameter and api

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I generate swagger from annotations for now and trying to clean up the generation in the short time while I move to schema first, so I have:

```java
    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(
                    name = "x-my-header-name", dataType = "string", paramType = "header", allowMultiple = true,
                    allowableValues = "A,B,C,D",
                    value = "Header defined presentation options"
            ),
     ...
    public Response processRequest(@HeaderParam("x-my-header-name") String myHeaderName) {
        return something;
    ...
```

The `HeaderParam` is there to map `x-my-header-name` to `myHeaderName` but generating swagger from this generates two entries for the same header:

```
        - name: x-my-header-name
          in: header
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: x-my-header-name
          in: header
          description: 'Header defined presentation options'
          required: false
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            enum:
              - A
              - B
              - C
              - D
          collectionFormat: csv
```

Is there a way to get swagger to either hide one or combine all the required information into one place without having to make a non standard header name or Java parameter name?

Comment: You need to use @ApiParam to change the name instead of using ApiImplicitParam:https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-apiparam-vs-apimodelproperty

ApiImplicitParam is for adding additional properties

Comment: @pinkpanther as an answer?

Comment: Did my suggestion work?

Comment: Just got a chance to try now, doesn't seem to have no :( I'll update the question.

Comment: It should be declared as part of the parameter, not as part of `ApiImplicitParams`. ```Response processRequest(@ApiParam("x-my-header-name")  @HeaderParam("x-my-header-name") String myHeaderName)```

Comment: Sorry, I take it back.  It did work, there was just also a duplicate endpoint I missed. @pinkpanther.

Comment: Great! Is it an answer for your question? May I add it as an answer?

Comment: Yes please @pinkpanther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@ApiParam` to change the name instead of using `ApiImplicitParam`

For reference, see: https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-apiparam-vs-apimodelproperty. `ApiImplicitParam` is for adding additional properties.

```
   Response processRequest(
     @ApiParam("x-my-header-name")  
     @HeaderParam("x-my-header-name") String myHeaderName) {
    //...
   }
```